# Indexed db loop through table data and send it to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, indexeddb

Hi all I have few tables where I am syncing data to server on a timely basis. I have 3 tables where the data has a relation to other table. I know the db is not relational but this is how I created

```
TableA
  TableAId   Column1  Column2
     1         xyz      ABC
     2         PQR      TCG

TableB
  TableBId  TableAId   Column1  Column2
     1         1         xyz      ABC
     2         2         PQR      TCG

TableC
  TableCId  TableBId   Column1  Column2
     1         1         xyz      ABC
     2         1         PQR      TCG
```

I have written some code to get all the data and send it to server one by one, the code is working when I have single row in each table. When I had the multiple rows the data is getting duplicated

This is the common method I wrote to get all the data

```
function getIndexeDbData(storeName, callback) {
    var myDB = window.indexedDB.open(dbName);
    myDB.onsuccess = function () {
        try {
            if (this.result.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
                this.result.transaction(storeName).objectStore(storeName).getAll().onsuccess = function (event) {
                    callback(event.target.result);
                };
            }
            else {
                callback(false);
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
        }
    };
}
```

This is how calling
FormData syncFormData =new FormData();

```
function SyncData() {
   getIndexeDbData("TableA", function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (i, tblAData) {
        FormData syncFormData = new FormData();
        syncFormData.append('TableA.Column1', tblAData.Column1);
        syncFormData.append('TableA.Column2', tblAData.Column2);
         getTable2(tblAData.TableAId)
      });
   });
}

function getTable2(id)
{
   getIndexeDbData("TableB", function (data) {
       var tblbData= data.filter(x => x.TableAId === id);
       syncFormData.append('TableB.Column1', tblbData.Column1);
        syncFormData.append('TableB.Column2', tblbData.Column2);
       getTable3(tblbData.TableBId);
   });
}

function getTable3(id)
{
   getIndexeDbData("TableC", function (data) {
       var tblCData= data.filter(x => x.TableBId === id);
       postToDb() // Where I am calling ajax to post to server
   });
}
```

Comment: Consider renaming your question to avoid using terms not known to many people such as `IIop`

Comment: Sorry it is a spelling mistake